# javascript canvas eventlistener 2 button simultaneously

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to create a game with javacript. My object can move in any 4 direction in the canvas. I'm trying to make it move diagonally. Have any ideas how to do that.

```
  this.move = function () {
        counter++;
        // Determine if the action is move action
        if (KEY_STATUS.left || KEY_STATUS.right || KEY_STATUS.down || KEY_STATUS.up || KEY_STATUS.shift || KEY_STATUS.ctrl) {
            // The ship moved, so erase it's current image so it can
            // be redrawn in it's new location
            this.context.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
            // Update x and y according to the direction to move and
            // redraw the ship. Change the else if's to if statements
            // to have diagonal movement.
            if (KEY_STATUS.left) {
                this.x -= this.speed;
                if (this.x <= 0) // Keep player within the screen
                    this.x = 0;
            }
            else if (KEY_STATUS.right) {
                this.x += this.speed;
                if (this.x >= this.canvasWidth - this.width) this.x = this.canvasWidth - this.width;
            }
            else if (KEY_STATUS.up) {
                console.log(this.y);
                this.y -= this.speed;
                if (this.y < 0) this.y = 0;
                //                if (this.y <= this.canvasHeight / 4 * 3) this.y = this.canvasHeight / 4 * 3;
            }
            else if (KEY_STATUS.down) {
                this.y += this.speed;
                if (this.y >= this.canvasHeight - this.height) this.y = this.canvasHeight - this.height;
                console.log(this.canvasHeight);
                console.log(this.height);
            }
            else if (KEY_STATUS.shift) {
                this.speed += 2;
            }
            else if (KEY_STATUS.ctrl) {
                if (this.speed > 2) {
                    this.speed -= 2;
                }
                else {
                    this.speed = 2;
                }
            }
            // Finish by redrawing the ship
            this.draw();
        }
        if (KEY_STATUS.space && counter >= fireRate) {
            this.fire();
            counter = 0;
        }
    };
```

So basically to move diagonally it should for exxample do;

```
this.x += this.speed;
```

but at the same time do:

```
this.y += this.speed;
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to adjust your else if conditions to if, in the case it can go in multiple directions.

For example, you probably don't want to move both up and down or left and right at the same side. So, on those cases you keep the `else if` conditions. Otherwise, just change the else if condition to an if condition.

I'm assuming you also can't press both `shift` and `control` at the same time.

Here's how your code should look.

`if (KEY_STATUS.left) {
                this.x -= this.speed;
                if (this.x <= 0) // Keep player within the screen
                    this.x = 0;
            }
            else if (KEY_STATUS.right) {
                this.x += this.speed;
                if (this.x >= this.canvasWidth - this.width) this.x = this.canvasWidth - this.width;
            }

            if (KEY_STATUS.up) {
                console.log(this.y);
                this.y -= this.speed;
                if (this.y < 0) this.y = 0;
                //                if (this.y <= this.canvasHeight / 4 * 3) this.y = this.canvasHeight / 4 * 3;
            }
            else if (KEY_STATUS.down) {
                this.y += this.speed;
                if (this.y >= this.canvasHeight - this.height) this.y = this.canvasHeight - this.height;
                console.log(this.canvasHeight);
                console.log(this.height);
            }
            if (KEY_STATUS.shift) {
                this.speed += 2;
            }
            else if (KEY_STATUS.ctrl) {
                if (this.speed > 2) {
                    this.speed -= 2;
                }
                else {
                    this.speed = 2;
                }
            }`